websocket connection failed in cpanel
I’ve created a simple chat application using PHP and the Ratchet library for WebSockets. However, I’m experiencing an issue when trying to connect to the server. The error message I receive is:

WebSocket connection to 'wss://mywebsite.com:8080/' failed.

I have already installed an SSL certificate on my website.
Could someone please help me troubleshoot this issue? Are there any common reasons for WebSocket connection failures, and how can I resolve this problem?
Thank you!
server.php
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Load Autoload

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage; // Store all active connections
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            // Don't send the message to the sender
            if ($from !== $client) {
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Detach the connection
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        $conn->close();
    }
}

$server = Ratchet\server\IoServer::factory(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\ConnectionInterface(new Chat())
    ),
    8080 // Choose a port
);
$server->run();

chat.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat Room</title>
    <style>
        body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
        #messages { border: 1px solid #000; height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll; }
        #input { width: calc(100% - 22px); }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Chat Room</h2>
    <div id="messages"></div>
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Type your message here..." />
    <script>
        var conn = new WebSocket('wss://mywebsite.com:8080');


        conn.onmessage = function(e) {
            var messagesDiv = document.getElementById('messages');
            messagesDiv.innerHTML += '<div>' + e.data + '</div>';
            messagesDiv.scrollTop = messagesDiv.scrollHeight;
        };

        document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
            if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                conn.send(this.value);
                this.value = '';
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>


How did you run the ratchet script? Most shared hosting systems don't let you execute long-running background tasks such as would be needed to rub your own websocket server

@ADyson I noticed that it runs automatically, and I also ran it from the terminal with the command with php server.php

OK. Did you check with the hosting company whether port 8080 is open on the server? It might be blocked by the firewall

@ADyson I've checked the port in server terminal and it's open and not blocked.
